# How do I verify a method call and ignore the return value in EasyMock

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I need to verify I method call with a specific parameters
How can I do?
Im work in java with mockito, and use junit.

Comment: Easymock or Mockito?  Please edit either the title, or the question body, so that they match.  Otherwise, it causes a problem for future people wanting to reference this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply provide the parameters you require in the verify statement, assuming that the classes for those parameters have the `equals` method properly defined.

```
verify(myMock).myMethodCall(someParmValue1, someParmValue2);
```

If `equals` is not the criteria you wish to use, you can use `Matcher`s on the arguments, but note that if you use a Matcher for *any* argument then you have to use matchers for *all* arguments.  So as an example if you want to ensure that the arguments in your verify were actually the same instances as (object identity instead of equality), you could use the `Matchers.same()` Matcher:

```
verify(myMock).myMethodCall( same(someParmValue1), same(someParmValue2));
```

Comment: Note: my answer is for Mockito, since that is what the question was tagged with.  I do not know EasyMock.

Comment: Thanks!, I´m use the both XD